# What are the breaking changes in clojure 1.3?

Tags: clojure

I have been having trouble keeping up with the list of changes in 1.3 and most importantly the changes that require me to change my code.

- What has changed,
- what is about to change,
- where can I get up to date lists of these?

Comment: woooo 1000th clojure question!

Comment: http://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/changes.txt is kept up to date.

Comment: should questions like this be community wiki?

Comment: changed to MarkDown format https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/changes.md

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Breaking changes to date:

- Math ops no longer promote into bignums.
- Math ops no longer narrow the result to the smallest type that can hold them.
- Vars will no longer default to being dynamically bindable. Add `^:dynamic` when needed.

Answer (score 6):

A couple of other numerical changes:

- There is a new literal for BigIntegers: `5N`, which is 5 as a BigInteger.
- The rules for equality have changed (perhaps arising as a result of the changes Alex mentions?):

  - `(= 2 2.0)` => `false`, but `(== 2 2.0)` => `true`
  - `(= 2 2M)` => `false`, but `(== 2 2M)` => `true`
  - `(= 2.0 2M)` => `false`, but `(== 2.0 2M)` => `true`
  - and for clarity:

    - `(= 2 2N)` => `true`
    - `(= 2 4/2)` => `true`
  - You can generally assume that you'll need `==` to compare floating-point numbers for equality (which is still probably a shaky proposition).